# Analysis of decision tree in sorting algorithms

Tags: algorithm, sorting, decision-tree

In a decision tree of height h in a sorting algorithm with n elements:

We have something like this:

```
n! <= 2^h
```

Hence h>=log(n!)

I know that n^n is greater than n!, but here we are talking about the lower bound of worst case scenario,the graph of log(n!) is lower than the graph of(log n^n). So simply the answer should be Ω(log n!) as it can't go any lower than that.

So how can we say after here that h= Ω(nlogn)..?

Comment: Not sure about the formalities, but: log(n!) = log(n * (n-1) * (n-2) ...) = log(n) + log(n-1) + log(n-2) ...[n summands] ~ n log(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that n! and n<sup>n</sup> have different growth rates, but their logs (log n! and log n<sup>n</sup>) actually have the same growth rate. @Salvador Dali has pointed out that Stirling's approximation is a great way to see this, but here's a different way to look at this.

First, note that log n<sup>n</sup> = n log n via properties of logarithms. That's the easy one.

What about (log n!)? First, notice that

> log n!
>
> = log (n · (n-1) · (n-2) · .. · 2 · 1)
>
> = log n + log (n-1) + log (n-2) + ... + log 2 + log 1

This again uses properties of logarithms. From this, we can see that log n! = O(n log n), since

> log n + log (n-1) + log (n-2) + ... + log 2 + log 1
>
> ≤ log n + log n + log n + ... + log n + log n  (n times)
>
> = n log n

I'm also going to claim that log n! = Ω(n log n). Here's one way to see this. Look at the first n/2 terms of the above summation, which is

> log n + log (n-1) + log(n-2) + ... + log(n/2)

Notice that this quantity is no smaller than

> log (n/2) + log (n/2) + log(n/2) + ... + log(n/2)  (n/2 times)
>
> = (n/2) log (n/2)

That last quantity is Ω(n log n), so overall we see that log n! = O(n log n) and that log n! = Ω(n log n), so n! = Θ(n log n). In other words, log n! grows asymptotically at the same rate as log n<sup>n</sup>, even though the original functions n! and n<sup>n</sup> have different growth rates.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Basically here is an approximation for your log(n!):

[image]

You can prove it from [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), which is an approximation of a `n!`:

[image]

There they also give you a slightly less tight approximation: [image]

If you are interested of how to prove it, just carefully use the log over the Stirling's formula.